# correct way to use python multiprocess/parallelization on large dataframe when there are custom functions with multiple arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocess as mp



# df_single dataframe handles each simulation set
# df_all handles the collective results
df_all = pd.DataFrame({'subject id':        [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5],
                        'trial id':          [1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                        'simulation id':     [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
                        '# events':            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                        'injury':            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})

df_one = pd.DataFrame({'subject id':     [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5], 
                    'trial id':          [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
                    'simulation id':     [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}
                    )



df_all.set_index(['subject id', 'trial id', 'simulation id'], inplace=True)
df_one.set_index(['subject id', 'trial id', 'simulation id'], inplace=True)



def foo_one(df_all, df_single, simulation_id):
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    df_single = df_single.reset_index()
    df_single['simulation id'] = simulation_id
    df_single.set_index(['subject id', 'trial id', 'simulation id'], inplace=True)

    # this is a simplified version, in reality the # of events is based on another dataframe with event set a and probability set p so I do need 2 dataframes.
    df_single['# events'] = df_single.index.map(lambda x: rng.choice(a=10))
    
    # generate an injury amount per event, calculate sum
    df_single['injury'] = df_single['# events'].apply(lambda x: sum(10*rng.choice(a=10, size=x)))

    # update the overall df
    df_all['# events'].update(df_single['# events'])
    df_all['injury'].update(df_single['injury'])

    return df_all
```

Assume 5 subjects, with ID's from 1 to 5.
Assume there are n (n=2 in this case) trials for each subject.
In each trial there are k (k=3 in this case) simulations.
Each simulation will generate a random number of events from the uniform distribution on range [0,10].  This is the df_one['# events'] column.
Each event produces an injury amount. For the sake of simpliciity, let's assume the total injury amount produced by all events in a particular simulation is a random integer between [1, 10 * # of events].
This would be the df_one['injury'] column.

I have a function foo_one(df_one, simulation_id) that basically produces a df_one, given a simulation_id, and updates the corresponding injury value in df_all that matches df_one's ['subject id', 'trial id', 'simulation id']. For simplicity reasons I've made the df_one simulation process simple, but in reality I do need to have them in separate dataframes.
My dataset is substantially larger, and since there are distributions involved, it can get slow.

Since foo_one takes simulation_id, I was thinking of splitting df_all into smaller dataframes. Then I want to use multiprocessing on each piece of the split df_all, and combine them at the end.

The multiprocess module is a fork of multiprocessing that allows for debugging in the VSC terminal.
Docs available here. https://pypi.org/project/multiprocess/

My sample code so far:

```
def foo_chunk(df_all_chunk, df_one):
    sims = df_all_chunk.index.get_level_values('simulation id').unique()
    for run in sims:
        foo_one(df_all_chunk, df_one, run)
    return df_all_chunk


def foo_two(df_sim_set, df_one):
    df_sim_set[0]=foo_chunk(df_sim_set[0], df_one)
    df_sim_set[1]=foo_chunk(df_sim_set[0], df_one)
    return df_all

num_cores = 3 
# number of partitions to split dataframe
sims_per_core = len(df_all.index.get_level_values('simulation id').unique())/num_cores 

# Split dataframe by index 'simulation id' by every n unique values. 
df_sim_set = [y for x, y in df_all.groupby(df_all.index.get_level_values('simulation id').factorize()[0]//sims_per_core)]

pool = mp.Pool(num_cores)
results = pd.concat(pool.starmap(foo_two, [(df_sim_set, df_one)]))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

However I'm not sure if I wrote foo_two correctly in order to properly parallelize. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'd be surprised if this approach is even possible, perhaps [parallel-pandas](https://pypi.org/project/parallel-pandas/) instead.

Comment: That's not valid code (unless you happen to have your own *multiprocess* module. What is *foo_two*? MRE please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Updated the codes to be MRE.

Comment: Changes to df_sim_set wouldn't propagate outside the multiprocessing subprocess.